# Regarding error in node modules while installing SlickGrid

Tags: node-modules, slickgrid

While installing latest version of Slickgrid 4.1.2 with angular 12, am facing issues while building with errors such as,

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-slickgrid/fesm2015/angular-slickgrid.mjs 2079:48-70
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-slickgrid/fesm2015/angular-slickgrid.mjs 67:259-277
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-slickgrid/fesm2015/angular-slickgrid.mjs 511:46-69
Can't import the named export 'castObservableToPromise' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

I tried various things, and made sure ngx/translate package is installed, in tsconfig am using es2015 because of my other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid

Angular-Slickgrid 4.x is for Ivy/ESM build only, as it is written in Angular-Slickgrid [README - Angular Compatibility](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid#angular-compatibility), and you seem to want to stay on non-ESM/non-Ivy builds by keeping ES2015 output and so you should use previous major version of Angular-Slickgrid 3.x and with that downgrade you will also have to downgrade any packages of Slickgrid-Universal to 0.x (if you had any).

Comment: Thanks, like the downgrading to previous major version works and also as you suggested in github window it was rxjs 6 and es2015 causing compatibility issues.

Comment: good to know that it works, if that answered the question then you can upvote the answer. I would still suggest to eventually upgrade to RxJS 7 it brings some nice new features. Thanks for using the lib